# Angular-material md-list-item full screen height sometimes

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Each list-item ends up full screen height when click actions are attached. It should only be large enough to enclose the text.

Below is a minimal example of the problem that shows the problem when opened as a file.

It works properly in codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOaPVy - , and it works properly when the click action is removed. I am viewing it in chrome browser on Linux.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <md-list ng-app="BlankApp">
    <md-list-item ng-click="null">
      <p> List item 1 </p>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item ng-click="null">
      <p> List item 2 </p>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a more simplified version of a similar question:
[Angular Material: Each md-list-item takes full page width and Sidenav have long scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147321/angular-material-each-md-list-item-takes-full-page-width-and-sidenav-have-long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced this very odd problem in Chrome and Safari on a MacBook. It doesn't appear in Firefox.

The culprit seems to be the 100% height of `_md-list-item-inner` of the `md-list-item`

[image]

If you add this to the `<head>` all should be good

```
<style>
  md-list-item._md-button-wrap>div.md-button:first-child ._md-list-item-inner {
    height: initial;
  }
</style>
```